# Cannot load resource in spring-data project

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-data

I am using spring-data project in combination with hadoop to run map-red jobs. My application context seems not to resolve classpath resources.

```
    <hdp:job id="myjob" input-path="wordcount/in/" output-path="wordcount/outtttt/"
         mapper="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.TokenizerMapper"
         reducer="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.IntSumReducer"
         jar="classpath:hadoop-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
         jar-by-class="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount"/>

<hdp:job-runner id="myjob-runner" job-ref="myjob" run-at-startup="true"/>
```

I see from my classpath when I run a program that jar is present:
-classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;... atd;C:\Users\JS185350\WorkSpace\HBasePlaying\hadoop-examples\target\hadoop-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;

Error creating bean with name 'myjob': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:hadoop-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Any guess what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a slash `/` in front of the `hadoop-examples...`

```
    <hdp:job id="myjob" input-path="wordcount/in/" output-path="wordcount/outtttt/"
         mapper="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.TokenizerMapper"
         reducer="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.IntSumReducer"
         jar="classpath:/hadoop-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
         jar-by-class="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount"/>

<hdp:job-runner id="myjob-runner" job-ref="myjob" run-at-startup="true"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly that doesn't work either. I even tried various cmbinations including classpath*:/hadoop-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. None worked